# What frameworks to use with JQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, node.js

I want to use some of the widgets found in JQuery UI in my node server. But I'm having problems in just even getting a progress bar to update.

What are the best frameworks to use with JQuery UI, and are there any examples of nodejs servers that use it?

Comment: you need the jQuery library :) http://jquery.com

Comment: jquery UI is used for enhancing the UI on the browser. From my understanding, node is a server-side web application framework. How would one use a UI framework on the server?

Comment: I need to pass new values to the client after the page is rendered in order to control JQuery UI widgets.

Comment: In that case what you need to do is to pass new values to the client after the page is rendered and control the JQuery UI widgets! jQuery and jQuery UI, both running client-side, will not care how the original page or the subsequent data gets served.

Comment: That's what I've been trying to do. I tried using express methods and socket.io to get those values to the client, but have not been able to get it to work, so I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use jQuery UI you only need `jQuery Liblary` and `jQuery UI Liblary` Both of them you can download from:

http://jqueryui.com/download

http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

Answer (score 1):

It's just the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) since jQuery UI is based on that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you know about twitter bootstrap.  But take a look it might have what you need and is extremely easy to use!  It uses jQuery.

[Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)